# mark a second type of holidays in calendar

Tags: calendar

Emacs `calendar` can show holidays, so I know when I'm required to stay at home. ;)
(lets say: these are marked with red background, and this feature is already working)

But what if I'm a teacher and like to see (in `calendar`) when my pupils are staying at home and I'm required to go to work. (lets say, I'd like to mark them with a green background)

How can I achieve this highligting of those second type of holidays?

Comment: Drew has a function in his `calendar+.el` library to customize/colorize calendar entries -- `mark-visible-calendar-date`:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/calendar%2B.el